# c++ Using a class' class variable's variable?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Circle` with the variables `center` of type `Location` and `radius` of type `int`. `Location` is a class with the variables `xPosition` and `yPosition`, both of which are of type `int`.

I have an instance of `Circle`, called `c`, which already has values assignmed to it's data members.

Now, if I want to do:

```
cout << "x: " << c.center.xPosition << " y:" << c.center.yPosition << endl;
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: Just like you have done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `xPosition` and `yPosition` variables in `Location` are public, the way you've written it should work.  But if they're private, you can't access them directly from outside the class; you'll need to provide accessor functions (e.g. `getXPosition()`) in the `Location` class, and then you'd write something like `c.center.getXPosition()`.

It would be better, though, to write an `operator<<` function that lets the `Location` class write *itself* to an output stream:

```
class Location {
public:
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Location const &location);

  // ...
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Location const &location) {
  stream << "x: " << location.xPosition
         << "y: " << location.yPosition;

  return *this;
}
```

Then you can write the whole `Location` object just by doing:

```
cout << c.center << endl;
```